# Cross-browser background Y position animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using this to animate background positions:

```
$('#icon' + n).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "-=5px" }, 250 );
$('#icon' + n).animate({ backgroundPositionY : "+=5px" }, 250 );
```

Chrome is warning me `backgroundPositionY` will be deprecated, also it get's buggy if zoom is different than 100% and Firefox and Explorer don't even run the animation.

What is the correct method to animate background Y position?

Comment: Could you use `$(".area").animate({"background-position": "+=3px 40px"}, "fast")` where the one dimension stays put and the other is animated?

Comment: I think I can do that getting the position previously and including it in the script. But it gets buggy at different zoom levels, don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of readily available plugins for background animation...dig into their source to see what methods they use